# Flutter How can I check if my device is connected to another device with Bluetooth or not

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bluetooth

I'm writing a Flutter Application which checks if My device is connected to another device, +-Blutooth device or no all.

What I find in Flutter documentation wasn't able to help me because I check first if the bluetooth is opened or not. I ask the user for it as it show in the code but I can't check if the device is connected. I did it with wifi but with bluetooth I can't.

```
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        color: Colors.lightBlue,
        home: StreamBuilder<BluetoothState>(
      stream: FlutterBlue.instance.state,
      initialData: BluetoothState.unknown,
      builder: (c, snapshot) {
        final state = snapshot.data;
        if (state == BluetoothState.off)
          // ignore: missing_return
         return Bluetoth();
        else return Find();
      }),
            );
          }

   // open bluetooth  if closed
         class BluetothState extends State<Bluetoth>
         {
         void initState(){
              super.initState();
            aa();
             }
           Future aa() async {
      // async lambda seems to not working
      print('ccc');
  await FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance.requestEnable();

       }
              class _FindState extends State<Find> {
                   //check bluetooth connectivity


              }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `connectedDevices` future:

```
var _flutterBlue = FlutterBlue.instance;
_flutterBlue.connectedDevices.then((value) {
  //Do your processing
});
```

Comment: it Always return True

Comment: It returns a device list, it cannot return a boolean value. What returns true?

Comment: a list ??? the device can only connect to a only a device at time